# Html background transparency

Tags: html, background-image, transparency

Can't seem to figure out how to set the transparency on this thing.

As you can see the first row and second row aren't same.

[image]

I have figured it out, took me sometime to,
Any suggestions for the text colors to match with the background image?

Need two colors for the thead and tbody.

Comment: do you have any code to go with this?

Comment: **[Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: I kinda figured it out, took me a lot of time. I just now want to know the colors that match with that background, any suggestions?

Comment: @YashAgarwal https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/

Comment: That's just a color Wheel, I needed Text on that background